# Memory allocation google cloud function signification

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I'm developping functions on the Google Cloud Functions using Firebase. I saw that each functions have a Memory Allocation but I can't find documentation describing the interest and signification of it.

From what I can understand, the more memory you are allocating, the more instance of the functions you can create at runtime. So, the more people are using my app, the more memory I need to allocate for each function.

Is it right to think like this? Does someone has a documentation for that?

Thanks in advance and have a good day!
Adrien

Answer (score 0):

Not quite, the memory allocation is in direct proportion to the function's resources and its virtual RAM. This can be helpful when dealing with processing bulk documents, images, video compression, etc.

I have also heard that increasing memory allocation increases in CPU frequency from 400mhz at 256mb of ram up to 8GB and 4.8ghz respectfully.
found at the end of the first part before `free tier`

https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#cloud-functions-pricing

Comment: Be careful, 8Gb means 4.8Ghz, but it's in reality 2 times 2.4Ghz. If your function isn't able to leverage multi-CPU processing, keep max 2Gb of memory